# DotnetHighCharts does not show negative values?

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I have values between -1 to 1 (-1, -0.25, -0.33, 0, 0.46, 1, ..... )

I want to show this on TimeDataWithIrregularIntervals Chart. But I does not show negative values.

[image]

I cant find any option to show negative values. There are a lot of examples without any options, but they can show nagetive values. What am I missing? How can I show negative values?

Thanks.

Comment: set the min. value http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

Comment: This is the answers. I set min value to 0. When I remove `min = 0;` It works. Thanks. If you write your comment as answer, I will accept that.

Comment: added.glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the min value for the Y axis as per your requirement.

[the api doc is here.](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min)